# why is making a bootable usb stick harder than making a bootable cd

Tags: linux, boot, bootloader

I am looking to make a bootable usb stick on mac osx,  so i can install an operating system on my eee pc.  However, it seems making a bootable usb is much harder than a cd.  May I ask why ?

many thanks

Comment: If you're asking "HOW" to make a bootable USB, that would be appropriate for SuperUser, but "why" questions aren't generally.

Comment: However, IMHO, the reason why bootable USB is "harder" is because it isn't as mainstream. If it was common for people to use bootable USB, there would be programs to do it for you. The reason Bootable CDs are "easy" is because that's been a normal purpose for CDs for a long time and so just about every CD burning program knows how to do it for you.

Comment: Manufacturers and distributors of OSes had an economic incentive to have PCs capable of booting from CDs in order to replace the costly, mistake-prone and less-reliable multi-floppy sets.  CDs are the least costly method of distributing software on a hard medium.  So there would naturally be convenient methods of making bootable CDs. Capability of booting from USB sticks is essentially end-user driven rather than initiated by a conglomerate like Microsoft Corp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the wrong software, it is most likely harder. Much like burning a bootable CD, if you're using the wrong software, it can be a difficult task? What OS are you trying to install on your Asus?

Chances are, seeing the `linux` tag, you're trying to create a bootable USB drive of some flavor of linux. If you are unfamiliar with creating USB bootable drives on OSX, I suggest that you look into UNetBootin's software. It works really well with creating bootable USB drives and is cross platform.

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thankyou.  so i can make a bootable usb on a mac (that has uefi), and that will boot on a windows machine with a bios ?

Comment: how hard is it to make one of these programs?    ie, could the main distro makers easily make such a program ?

Comment: The BIOS/UEFI of the Host OS is irrelevant to the creation of the USB Bootable Drive. You should not have any issues with your question. It is not too hard to make one of these programs and the distributor of the OS could build one of these. However, you have to ask, with good tools already in existent, is there a point to do this? Especially, if it is not bringing value to their product. Instead, I would see worth in having them link to a tool where they can burn them to a USB drive. Ubuntu does this.